# Access-Control-Allow-Origin' not allowed access SharePoint Ajax call cross domain

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, api, cross-domain

I am trying to access cross domain service using ajax call in sharepoint.
getting below error 
Failed to 
**"Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin"**

below header i am passing :
 [image]

How to set authentication model to allow cross-domain access?